# Programmatically change header summary

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have a preference_headers.xml file that I use to populate the headers for my settings. I would like to change the summary of the header to reflect the sharedPreference it holds. I have used an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener for my other fragments and it works fine, but those are fragments under a preference screen, so I can access them like this..

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
        EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("pref_text");
        editTextPref
                .setSummary(sp.getString("pref_text", "Set an email address"));
```

However, I want to edit the summary in the preference_headers file which is an intent to another activity, so I am not using a preference screen to store the shared preference.

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<header
    android:key="snooze_pref"
    android:summary="Default snooze is 10 minutes"
    android:title="Snooze Timer" >
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass="com.example.alarmvoltageservicev2.SnoozePicker"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.alarmvoltageservicev2" />
</header>
```

**So my question is, how can I change the header summary above programmatically?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are extending class [**PreferenceActivity**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), in your override of the [**onBuildHeaders**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onBuildHeaders(java.util.List<android.preference.PreferenceActivity.Header>)) method, after calling **LoadHeadersFromResource**, simply iterate through the "target" list that is passed to **onBuildHeaders**.

The list is of type [**Header**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.Header.html) which provides access to the summary text, as well as other settings.

(Sorry, I would provide a code example, but I write in C#-monodroid).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the summary programmatically when you set your `ListAdapter` by iterating through the `Headers`:

```
@Override
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)
{
    int i, count;

    if (preferenceHeaders == null)
    {
        preferenceHeaders = new ArrayList<Header>();

        count = adapter.getCount();
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            Header h = (Header) adapter.getItem(i);

            if(h.id == R.id.SOME_HEADER_ID_FROM_XML)
            {
                h.summary = "<new summary at runtime>";
            }
        }
    }

    super.setListAdapter(new PreferencesHeaderAdapter(this, preferenceHeaders));
}
```